# I want to count the Specific number in each column in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, count

I want to count the number of times either of the specific values **4** & **5** appear in each column of a pandas DataFrame, proportionately.

**Given this dataframe as input:**

```
| A | B | C | D | E |
|---|---|---|---|---|
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
```

...first get raw counts per column, something like this...:

```
| A | B | C | D | E |
|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

...then I want to divide the counts for each column, to get proportionate counts:

**Desired Output:**

```
| A    | B    | C    | D    | E    |
|------|------|------|------|------|
| 0.33 | 0.66 | 0.33 | 0.66 | 0.33 |
```

I tried the following 
`df.counts()` but this only returns me the total no. of counts

Comment: You can use `for` loop and when the program finds 4s or 5s just increase the `i` file by one and then divide with each column (you can use `df.counts()` in this case.

Comment: @NijatMursali Can you help me out to implement this. I am Newbie here.

Comment: I cannot help, unless I see what you have done. You have to show your code and what exactly you did.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For the future, the rules require questions to have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. executable code and data. Please click edit on your question to add those on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for get mask, for count values use `sum` and for ratio use `mean`, last for one row DataFrame add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with transpose:

```
mask = df.isin([4,5])
df1 = mask.sum().to_frame().T
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  1  1  1

df2 = mask.mean().to_frame().T
#or division
#df2 = df1.div(len(df))

print (df2)
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.333333  0.666667  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

EDIT: Solution with groupby by `Head Manager` is by create index by `Head Manager`, then test membership and count `sum` or `mean`:

```
print (df)
  Head Manager  A  B  C  D  E
0         man1  3  3  1  2  1
1         man1  5  5  4  4  3
2         man1  3  4  1  1  5

df11 = df.set_index('Head Manager').isin([4,5]).sum(level=0)
#alternative
#df11 = df.set_index('Head Manager').isin([4,5]).groupby(level=0).sum()
print (df11)
                A    B    C    D    E
Head Manager                         
man1          1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

df22 = df.set_index('Head Manager').isin([4,5]).mean(level=0)
#alternative
#df22 = df.set_index('Head Manager').isin([4,5]).groupby(level=0).mean()
print (df22)
                     A         B         C         D         E
Head Manager                                                  
man1          0.333333  0.666667  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Alternative with `groupby.apply`, but is is slow if many groups:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Head Manager'])
df22 = df.groupby('Head Manager')[cols].apply(lambda x: x.isin([3,4]).mean())
print (df22)
                     A         B         C         D         E
Head Manager                                                  
man1          0.666667  0.666667  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

If want specify some columns:

```
df22 = df.groupby('Head Manager')['A','B','C','D','E'].apply(lambda x: x.isin([3,4]).mean())
```

Comment: I have the above dataframe by using GROUPBY, And I am getting this error `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'isin' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
`

Comment: This is how i created the GROUPBY object. `group_data = b.groupby('Head Manager')`

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - So there is also colum `Head Manager` in input data?

Comment: Yes, There is `Head Manager` column in Dataframe but then i GROUPBY by `Head manager` it for Analysis

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - added solution with `groupby`, please check it.

Comment: I am getting following error: ``AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'set_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method``

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - do you use - `df22 = df.set_index('Head Manager').isin([4,5]).groupby(level=0).mean()` ? groupby is used in last step.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - added another solution, please check last paragraph.

Comment: This is how i tried your code `p = group_data['P001','P002','P003','P004','P005'].set_index('Head Manager').isin([4,5]).groupby(level = 0).mean()`

Comment: After performing groupby I have selected few column which i want to get the percent count.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar - OK, added solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

Straightforwardly:

```
In [54]: (df[(df == 4) | (df == 5)].count() / df.index.size).to_frame().T                                                    
Out[54]: 
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.333333  0.666667  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[3, 3, 1, 2, 1], [5, 5, 4, 4, 3], [3, 4, 1, 1, 5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
nums_to_count = [4, 5]
count_of_nums = df.isin(nums_to_count).sum()
total_nums = df.count()
share_of_nums = count_of_nums / total_nums
```

Where "share_of_nums" is you desired output.

or to keep it neat:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[3, 3, 1, 2, 1], [5, 5, 4, 4, 3], [3, 4, 1, 1, 5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
    nums_to_count = [4, 5]
    share_of_nums = df.isin(nums_to_count).sum() / df.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the occurrence of each number:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([df[col].value_counts()/len(df) for col in df.columns])[[4,5]].T
      A         B   C         D
4.0 NaN  0.333333 NaN       NaN
5.0 NaN       NaN NaN  0.333333
```